# Cannot execute bash scripts directly from external drive

Tags: linux, shell

I have a bit of a puzzler: I cannot seem to directly execute scripts from my external drive on my Debian box.

Executing them through `bash` works, but shebangs don't seem to work.

```
<user>@<host>:<directory>$ ls -ll ./dl.sh
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ cp ~/dl.sh ./dl.sh
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ ./dl.sh
bash: ./dl.sh: Permission denied
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ ~/dl.sh
foo
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ bash ./dl.sh
foo
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ cat ./dl.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo"
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ ls -ll ./dl.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 <user> <user> 24 Aug  2 18:35 ./dl.sh
<user>@<host>:/media/external$ ls -ll ~/dl.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 <user> <user> 24 Aug  2 18:34 /home/<user>/dl.sh
```

(Parts in `<braces>` are redacted.)

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands) question, you need 2 things to be able to directly run a shell script:

1. Script is marked executable and readable for the user in question. This is true.
2. Script is prefixed with the proper shebang line. This is also true, or else running it from my home directory wouldn't work.

I'm obviously missing something here, likely something obvious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I was 95% of the way through writing the question when I figured out the answer, as per usual with such things.

It was acting as though the script was still marked as non-executable. Why? ...because the *filesystem* was `noexec`.

I had looked at fstab, which shows the following:

```
/dev/mapper/external /media/external               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user,nofail 0       2
```

This doesn't *directly* state that the drive is non-executable. However, as it turns out, `user` [implies](https://superuser.com/a/968823/331815) `noexec` unless overridden by subsequent options.

Had I looked at the output of `mount` instead of in fstab, I probably could have figured this out in substantially less time.